# Spark: Importing Data

Tags: apache-spark

I currently have a spark app that reads a couple of files and forms a data frame out of them and implements some logic on the data frames.

I can see the number and size of these files growing by a lot in the future and wanted to understand what goes on behind the scenes to be able to keep up with this growth.

**Firstly**, I just wanted to double check that since all machines on the cluster can access the files (which is a requirement by spark), the task of reading in data from these files is distributed and no one machine is burdened by it?
I was looking at the Spark UI for this app but since it only shows what actions were performed by which machines and since "sc.textFile(filePath)" is not an action I couldn't be sure what machines are performing this read.

**Secondly**, what advantages/disadvantages would I face if I were to read this data from a database like Cassandra instead of just reading in files?

**Thirdly**, in my app I have some code where I perform a collect (val treeArr = treeDF.collect()) on the dataframe to get an array and then I have some logic implemented on those arrays. But since these are not RDDs, how does Spark distribute this work? Or does it distribute them at all? 
In other words, should I be doing maximum amount of my work transforming and performing actions on RDDs than converting them into arrays or some other data structure and then implementing the logic like I would in any programming language?

I am only about two weeks into Spark so I apologize if these are stupid questions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, `sc.textFile` is distributed. It even has an optional `minPartitions` argument.
2. This question is too broad. But the short answer is that you should benchmark it for yourself.
3. `collect` fetches all the data to the master. After that it's just a plain array. Indeed the idea is that you should not use `collect` if you want to perform distributed computations.